# Is there a way to tell Gradle to always search in cache and then search online?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

NPM acts like that, Nuget acts like that. They first search their global cache to see if they find a match of the requested dependency, then if not found, they fallback online automatically, find the requested dependency, cache it for future reuse and everything works just fine.

With Gradle it doesn't seem to be the case. When building, it notifies "go offline" and when going offline by adding a new dependency it can't find it and complaints that "no match found in cache for x in offline mode".

Is there a way to tell Gradle/Android Studio to not be so dumb and automatically do these things?

I mean this problem is solved for decades. The very concept of **fallback** and **priority/order** has been there from the beginning of the time. Why Gradle can't follow such a simple pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Gradle does what you describe and expect. However, if it has been configured in *offline* mode, which appears to be your case, then it will *not* go online if things are missing in the local cache.

Comment: In my country, access to maven centers are limited and Google returns 403. When I try to build the project, it complains that it can't get the metadata from some URL and breaks and only gives me the option to configure gradle in *offline mode*. But if your answer is true, it could simply bypass the URL and check the local cache, because files are already cached once.